# Confusion with Sync gateway Pull Replication on Android

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am trying to setup Channel based Pull replication on a Android device. I am using the Grocery-Sync Android client to push some data and retrieving the same through my Android client(push and Pull replication).

Here's my database configuration from the sync gateway file:

```
"cb":{
  "server":"http://172.17.0.5:8091",
  "users": { "GUEST": { "disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] } },
   "allow_empty_password": true,
 "sync":``function(doc){
        if(doc.type == "LatestUpdate"){
                console.log("Inside LatestUpdate");
            channel(doc.kidId);
        }
        else{
            channel(doc.channels);
        }
    }
```

I have set custom property called kidId(hardcoded for the time being) while pushing the data from the Grocery-sync app. The Push replication works alright. Even it pushes to the correct channel as is evident from the logs:

`Doc "afd8c40b-4431-49ab-be08-c87e409ee912" in channels "{2bea2709e58a49329de59c47d98535b}"`
Now, when I pull the data from my app, even though I have explicitly set a different channel, the logs suggest that it has still pulled the data.

Here's my Pull Replication code:

```
Replication pull = myApp.getDatabase().createPullReplication(url);
List<String> channels = new ArrayList<>();
channels.add("xyz");
pull.setContinuous(true);
pull.start();
pull.addChangeListener(this);
pull.setChannels(channels);
```

Is this correct behaviour or is something incorrect at my end? My assumption is that the Pull replication code shouldn't even have been looking at the data coming in from a different channel. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Is the syntax error (double apostrophe before your sync function) actually in your config file? If so, try enclosing the sync function in apostrophes to make sure it is correctly treated by the sync gateway.

Comment: No the sync function works fine.. I had posted the question on github as well and the extra ` would have been used for a markdown there.